# Master Pages - Sharepoint 2007

Tags: sharepoint-2007

I have created a Master Page in Sharepoint 2007.  I am having difficulty with the main content.  I have tried putting the content into the PlaceHolder Main but the content will not render on the page, the content consists of images (which I will eventually link to other pages).  If I go outside the PlaceHolder and create a div and div id and connect the div id to my css it will render on the master page.  That brings up a totally different issue, not only do the images render on the master page, but they also show up in all of my document libraries.

I have spent many hours trying to figure this out.  I do not want to change any application pages.  I have tried to apply the changes to the master page and not the rest of the site, I could not get that to work.  I have tried moving the content to different Placeholders and the images still render in the libraries. Someone please help me to understand why the images from the master page show up in all of the document libraries.  I would really really appreciate it.

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

Standard ASP.NET page generating at work here. The content in the master page content zone is replaced with the content in the page layout content zone. Without changing the application page you are stuck.

It sounds like you should be editing the application page anyway (because you don't want it to appear in all document libraries)

Comment: Why won't the images render when I put them in Content PlaceHolderMain?  This is a network with a large company, if I change the application pages, won't the effect happen across the entire network?

Comment: The content you put in the masterpage PlaceHolderMain is replaced with the content in the application page PlaceHolderMain. What page specifically are you talking about.